# using SQL_SAFE_UPDATES on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want insert this sql command in my PHP site , to avoid update on entire tables.

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;

It was written that it alows only WHERE with KEY fields or limit

what if I try statements like this: (countryId is defined INDEX, but not PRIMARY. name isn't INDEX)

UPDATE clients SET name='bb' WHERE name='gg' AND countryId=2

Would it be Ok?

Answer (score 0):

With SQL_SAFE_UPDATES on, you will need to include the primary key or composite key. In your case, the where clause does not use the primary key (unless name is a primary key), thus MySQL would return an error.

Comment: That's one way to get around it but you have to note that it might defeat the purpose of setting SQL_SAFE_UPDATES to 1 in the first place.